# WkWebView reloads itself when i use 2 Dialogs

Tags: angular, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have the following problem:
I use wkwebview from xamarin.ios and web is angular client. 
I call dialog1 and in dialog1 i call dialog2. 
If dialog2 was called, wkwebview reload the page. 
With Android such a problem i don't have. 
What interesting is, in DEBUG Modus it works 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be better to provide the relevant code so that people can help you better .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT , i was wrong. My fault is similar with https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Problem is solved](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/337#issuecomment-539414961)

That helped me :) Tnx !

Comment: Congratulations! Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people who has similar problems  :)